# Steam запуск кастомной игры

Tags: javascript, node.js, steam-web-api, steam

Надо запустить стороннюю игру в steam.
При помощи [steam](https://www.npmjs.com/package/steam) можно запустить игру по ее ID.
Но как запустить игру не связаную со Steam
[image: Игра не связанная со Steam]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Узнать id сторонней игры в Steam можно, создав ярлык на рабочем столе из библиотеки игр, в свойствах ярлыка будет ссылка типа *steam://rungameid/16129557454605254656*, где *16129557454605254656* - id сторонней игры.

Собственно запустить игру из браузера можно вызовом ссылки из ярлыка.

Возможно на разных компьютерах id сторонней игры будет разной, не проверял.

Comment: Я попробовал запустить игру по ее id. Она запустилась но почему то не пишет название просто пишет В игре, не связанной со Steam

Comment: @Kasper если указать в свойствах игры в библиотеке имя, то оно корректно отображается в профиле при открытии по ссылке (проверял на последней стабильной версии Steam)

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае *никак*. Steam использует свою службу, которая слушает запросы по протоколу `steam://`. "Кастомная" игра такой службы не имеет. При желании её можно написать, но учитывая, что игры могут быть разбросаны в любым местах системы, это является трудоемкой и почти не реализуемой задачей.